# How to create a route for two namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces

I'm trying to split my rails project in a front-end for regular users and a back-end for admins. Therefore i have created a namespace 'admin' so that i can easily control admin.After creating the admin namespace the I changed the routes from

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 authenticated :user do
    root to: 'dashboard#index', as: :authenticated_root
  end

  unauthenticated do
    root to: "home#index"
  end

  match '(errors)/:status', to: 'errors#show', constraints: { status: /\d{3}/ }, via: :all

  devise_for :users, skip: [:registrations]
  as :user do
    get 'my/profile/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', as: 'edit_user_registration'
    patch 'my/profile' => 'devise/registrations#update', as: 'user_registration'
  end

  resources :users

  resources :events do
    patch :archive, :unarchive
  end
end
```

to this

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    authenticated :user do
      root to: 'dashboard#index', as: :authenticated_root
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root to: "home#index"
    end

    match '(errors)/:status', to: 'errors#show', constraints: { status: /\d{3}/ }, via: :all

    devise_for :users, skip: [:registrations]
    as :user do
      get 'my/profile/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', as: 'edit_user_registration'
      patch 'my/profile' => 'devise/registrations#update', as: 'user_registration'
    end

    resources :users

    resources :events do
      patch :archive, :unarchive
    end
  end
end
```

After these change I got this page

```
Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you ask, you want to put everything admin related into the admin namespace, but leave everything (for example, the root page) outside.

But in your routing example, you put everything inside the admin namespace, even the root page.

So generally, you want something like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    # put admin stuff here
  end

  # put everything NOT in the admin interface outside your namespace
  # you want a root route here. That's the page that'll be displayed by default      
  root to :your_root_stuff

  # and if you have users who aren't admins, devise and authenticated routes too
  # ... other stuff
end
```